# Div not float as expected?

Tags: html, css

I have an annoying problem with my HTML page.
Here you can see my webpage: http://jgeneration.altervista.org/layout3.html

If you don't resize the window of your browser, you'll see it right, but if you do it then something strange happens. The first three divs of the second row get moved into a kind of new row when the second div of the first row gets bigger.

That's what happens:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU854.png)

I want the divs to be like a waterfall like style, so they must adapt their position according to the height of the other ones.

Here's my HTML & CSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Muzic4U</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

<div style="max-width: 100%; background-color: #0099FF; text-align: center; color: #fff; padding: 20px; margin: 0;">
 <h1 style="margin: 0;"> Muzic4U </h1>
</div>

  
<div id="main">
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="http://cdn.albumoftheyear.org/album/25168-blast-radius.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Insight </b><br> <i>The Blast Radius</i><br>2004</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="http://static.marapcana.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Orgasmi-Meccanici-cover.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Alien Army </b><br> <i>Orgasmi Meccanici</i><br>1999</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="http://img.maniadb.com/images/album/187/187420_1_f.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Surreal & The Sound Providers </b><br> <i>True Indeed</i><br>2003</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
 
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b> <br> <i>The Find</i> <br> 2005 </p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <span class="clear"></span>
  
</div>

<style>
 body {
  font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #333;
 }
 
  /* unvisited link */
 a:link {
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 /* visited link */
 a:visited {
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 /* mouse over link */
 a:hover {
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 /* selected link */
 a:active {
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 img {
   display: table-cell;
   max-width: 100%;
 }
 
 #main {
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
   max-width: 70%;
 }
 
 .tab {
   max-width: calc((100% / 5) - 5px);
   background-color: #666;
   text-align: center;
   float: left;
   display: inline-block; 
   margin: 0 5px 5px 0; 
   }
 
 .dw {
   max-width: 100%;
   background-color: #000;
   padding: 10px;
 }
 
 span.clear {
   clear: left;
   display: block;
 }
 
 .caption {
   font-size: smaller;
 }   
    
</style>

</body>
```

Thank you for the support.

Comment: A single CSS rule will solve the issue. No Javascript, no jQuery, no cutting off text etc. See my answer below. If you need to avoid whitespace between items due to one or several "longer" items in a row, you will have to resort to for example Masonry. (Google for that then.)

Comment: Has your question been answered? If so, pick your answer. If no, comment accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because when the page gets smaller the text from the third `<p class="caption">` needs one more line.

give your `.caption` following style:

```
.caption {
font-size: smaller;
min-height: 80px;
}
```

So all p-tags have the same height and the float will work again. If it happens again when it gets even smaller you maybe need to increase the px-size of min-height. Here is a code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Muzic4U</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

<div style="max-width: 100%; background-color: #0099FF; text-align: center; color: #fff; padding: 20px; margin: 0;">
 <h1 style="margin: 0;"> Muzic4U </h1>
</div>

  
<div id="main">
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="http://cdn.albumoftheyear.org/album/25168-blast-radius.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Insight </b><br> <i>The Blast Radius</i><br>2004</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="http://static.marapcana.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Orgasmi-Meccanici-cover.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Alien Army </b><br> <i>Orgasmi Meccanici</i><br>1999</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="http://img.maniadb.com/images/album/187/187420_1_f.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Surreal & The Sound Providers </b><br> <i>True Indeed</i><br>2003</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
 
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b> <br> <i>The Find</i> <br> 2005 </p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <span class="clear"></span>
  
</div>

<style>
 body {
  font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #333;
 }
 
  /* unvisited link */
 a:link {
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 /* visited link */
 a:visited {
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 /* mouse over link */
 a:hover {
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 /* selected link */
 a:active {
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 img {
   display: table-cell;
   max-width: 100%;
 }
 
 #main {
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
   max-width: 70%;
 }
 
 .tab {
   max-width: calc((100% / 5) - 5px);
   background-color: #666;
   text-align: center;
   float: left;
   display: inline-block; 
   margin: 0 5px 5px 0; 
   }
 
 .dw {
   max-width: 100%;
   background-color: #000;
   padding: 10px;
 }
 
 span.clear {
   clear: left;
   display: block;
 }
 
 .caption {
   font-size: smaller;
      min-height: 80px;
 }   
    
</style>

</body>
```

Comment: Provide a SO snippet that proves your answer works, and I'll +1 you!

Answer (score 2):

Marcel's solution is good, another approach however would be to use this bit of css code on your caption:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap; /* Don't forget this one */
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

So that if your text is too long (longer than 4 lines in this case) it will be replaced by '...'. That way you won't get that extra line that breaks your floats.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Muzic4U</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

<div style="max-width: 100%; background-color: #0099FF; text-align: center; color: #fff; padding: 20px; margin: 0;">
 <h1 style="margin: 0;"> Muzic4U </h1>
</div>

  
<div id="main">
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="http://cdn.albumoftheyear.org/album/25168-blast-radius.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Insight </b><br> <i>The Blast Radius</i><br>2004</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="http://static.marapcana.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Orgasmi-Meccanici-cover.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Alien Army </b><br> <i>Orgasmi Meccanici</i><br>1999</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="http://img.maniadb.com/images/album/187/187420_1_f.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Surreal & The Sound Providers </b><br> <i>True Indeed</i><br>2003</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
 
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b><br> <i>The Find</i><br>2005</p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COxJmdQWcAAFauN.jpg" />
 <p class="caption"> <b> Ohmega Watts </b> <br> <i>The Find</i> <br> 2005 </p>
 <div class="dw">
   <a href="">Download</a>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <span class="clear"></span>
  
</div>

<style>
 body {
  font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #333;
 }
 
  /* unvisited link */
 a:link {
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 /* visited link */
 a:visited {
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 /* mouse over link */
 a:hover {
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 /* selected link */
 a:active {
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 img {
   display: table-cell;
   max-width: 100%;
 }
 
 #main {
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
   max-width: 70%;
 }
 
 .tab {
   max-width: calc((100% / 5) - 5px);
   background-color: #666;
   text-align: center;
   float: left;
   display: inline-block; 
   margin: 0 5px 5px 0; 
   }
 
 .dw {
   max-width: 100%;
   background-color: #000;
   padding: 10px;
 }
 
 span.clear {
   clear: left;
   display: block;
 }
 
 .caption {
   font-size: smaller;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }   
    
</style>

</body>
```

Comment: I always forget about this one but it's quite good. Provide a working SO snippet and I'll upvote.

Comment: I tried it into the stackoverflow snippet and it works, but if I do the same on my local code, it doesn't work... Dunno why

Comment: Did you get it to work ? If not, did you apply these css parameters to the right html tag ?

Answer (score 1):

Everytime your text goes on two lines you will get that effect. To improve and to achieve the desired solution the best way is to `equal_heights()`.

1.Include the jQuery library in your project:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2.Use this script:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    equal_heights();
}).resize(function(){
    equal_heights();
});

function equal_heights(){
    _max = 0;

    $('.tab .caption').removeAttr('style');

    $('.tab').each(function(){
        _height = $('.caption', this).height();

        if (_max < _height) {
            _max = _height;
        };
    });

    $('.tab .caption').height(_max);
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/6LLgguq0/

Comment: I've added jsfiddle in my post so you can see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution (for a fixed number n of items per row) is to apply a `clear: left;` to every nth+1 item:

```
#main div:nth-of-type(5n+1) { 
    clear: left; 
}
```